# Weird Kinematics Homework

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, electric-fields

Here's another "hard" homework question I was given on how printers work. (I find it more confusing than it is hard.)

[image]

I'm supposed to find the horizontal velocity of  a charged droplet as it leaves the electric plates. This question is worth one single mark.

I tried using the potential difference between the electric plates to compute the acceleration the droplets faced while within the plates, but the potential difference is unknown and the charge of the droplet is unknown. Most importantly, this is too much work for one single mark, and I therefore suspect that I am missing out on something small yet very important.

Any ideas?

Comment: Find 'x' using the height and 35°, next calculate the time taken to reach the gutter taking gravity into consideration. Finally, use the time and the value of 'x' to get the horizontal velocity which is constant. I sometimes find that these supposedly long and complicated problems have the simplest solutions. Let me know if it works!

Comment: Happens to me all the time :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You know how much it will take for the drop to fall from the end of the plates to the gutter. And since you should be able to calculate the distance "x" then you have a distance to be covered in a certain time thus obtaining the velocity it has (by requirement).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it helps, but in the fifth chapter of the first volume of the book *Um Curso de Física Básica* (It is in Portuguese, the title in English would be "*A Course in Basic Physics*") by H. M. Nussenzveig there is a good presentation of a very similar situation to this, ending with a discussion of the deflection of an electron beam in a cathode ray tube.